# The difference of cubed diffrence of Wiener processes

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, brownian-motion

**Problem**
I need to calculate the limit of $X_n$ in mean squared when $n$ tends to infinity. $X_n$ is given as

$$X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (W_{ti/n} - W_{t(i-1)/n})^3$$

where $W$ is [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process).

**My attempt**
If we prove that $E(X_n) = 0$ and $Var(X_n) \to 0$, we are done.
However, I get stuck at the very beginning when I try to calculate the expectation.

**Issues**
If we denote $W_{ti/n}$ as $Y_i$, I struggle evaluating $E(Y_i^2Y_{i-1})$ after rising the difference to cube. Even though I showed that $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n Y_{i-1}$ are *almost* the same with the exception of $Y_n$ and $Y_0$, I don't know how to get that $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $Y_i-Y_{i-1}$ is independent of $Y_{i-1}$ and $\mathsf{E}Y_i^k=0$ for odd $k$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}Y_i^2Y_{i-1}&=\mathsf{E}[(Y_i-Y_{i-1})^2Y_{i-1}]+2\mathsf{E}[(Y_i-Y_{i-1})Y_{i-1}^2]+\mathsf{E}Y_{i-1}^3 \\
&=\mathsf{E}[(Y_i-Y_{i-1})^2]\mathsf{E}Y_{i-1}+2\mathsf{E}[Y_i-Y_{i-1}]\mathsf{E}Y_{i-1}^2+\mathsf{E}Y_{i-1}^3=0.
\end{align}

---

Alternatively, notice that $Z_i:=Y_i-Y_{i-1}\sim N(0,t/n)$ so that $\mathsf{E}Z_i^k=0$ for odd $k$, which implies that $\mathsf{E}X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf{E}Z_i^3=0$. Next, since the increments of $(W_t)$ are independent,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathsf{E}Z_i^6=5!!\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{t}{n}\right)^3=\frac{15 t^3}{n^2}.
$$